# How to download music in Zune

Tags: windows-phone, zune-software

I want to buy music in the Zune Marketplace . But when searching, I never get results regarding music only video.

Any idea how to find something?
I've tried "Goldengel Ambient" to search and I can find stuff. But nothing on Zune.

I am from Switzerland. Perhaps it is regarding the country?

[image: Music does not work in Zune]

Comment: The music you can see in the Zune marketplace is very dependent on what country you are in. What country are you trying to do this from?

Comment: like written above "Switzerland". But there is completely NO music from marketplace. Can you do any screenshot of your search, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this site that list's the various Windows Phone 7 features, Switzerland didn't get any music store. Microsoft has been quite bad at rolling out the music store.

http://andrewtechhelp.com/andrews-tech-opinions/126-windows-phone-7-feature-availability-matrix-the-mango-edition